# Adding multiple values form database into RichList Blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am using Blackberry Plug-in and i am using Rich Lists of blackberry.
I want to make lists appear the same number of times as there are entries in the database table.
I m using the below code but it shows only one name in list view.
I need to show all the entries in database into list view...Kindly help me..

I have already used list.add(); inside the for loop but it is showing Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Field added to a manager while it is already parented.

```
     public static void richlistshow(){

    String name = null;


    list = new RichList(mainManager, true, 2, 0);

    Bitmap logoBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("delete.png");
    delete = new BitmapField(logoBitmap, Field.FIELD_HCENTER);

    for (int c = 0; c < target_list.size();c++){

        City tar_city = new City();
        tar_city = (City)target_list.elementAt(c);

        name = tar_city.get_city_name().toString();

         }

            //adding lists to the screen
    list.add(new Object[] {delete,name,"time-date"});

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't posted full codes you are working with. But following code may help you to get rid of `IllegalStateException`. You were adding same `BitmapField` instance for every list entries, which caused the exception.

```
public static void richlistshow() {
    final Bitmap logoBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("delete.png");

    list = new RichList(mainManager, true, 2, 0);

    for (int c = 0; c < target_list.size(); c++) {
        // create a new BitmapField for every entry.
        // An UI Field can't have more than one parent.
        final BitmapField delete = new BitmapField(logoBitmap, Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
        City tar_city = (City) target_list.elementAt(c);
        final String name = tar_city.get_city_name().toString();
        // add to list
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                list.add(new Object[] { delete, name, "time-date" });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Rupak.. thanks for replying.........I m sorry for not defining the problem properly................................................here what i want to do is:-- adding "delete" button , name of the field from database and some time-date value in the richlist.......The values entered inside the richlist should be all the values from database i.e. all the 'name' and along with it i want to select this list to use it on some other place.....if possible to select a rich list and access its contents.

Comment: I am not sure if you can add a button ("delete") on RichList. And I didn't get your problem well. Are you having problem with reading data from data base? If you can read them then it might be possible to attach them with the RichList and later get them back.